# Preprocessing data for ggplot2 barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

How do I turn the example data into a format suitable for a bar-plot in ggplot2? (without hand coding the example data as below).

Example data

```
df <- list()
df$group <- c("a", "a",  "a", "a","a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
df$levels <- c("1", "2", "3", "3", "3","2", "1", "3", "1")

df$freq <- interaction(df$group, df$levels)
table(df$freq)
```

How i would like to be:

```
Hand-coded dataset
grp <- c(rep("a" , 3) , rep("b" , 3) )
lev <- rep(c("1" , "2" , "3") , 2)
value <- c(1, 1, 3,  2, 1, 1)
data <- data.frame(grp,lev,value)

plotted
ggplot(data, aes(fill=grp, y=value, x=lev)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop `stat="identity"` and `y=value` from your plotting code:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("a", "a",  "a", "a","a", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
  levels = c("1", "2", "3", "3", "3","2", "1", "3", "1")  
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(fill = group,x = levels)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

[image]